# How to Lookup Values from Another Column and check if its a duplicate and then delete row in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for some help to try and delete a number of rows from my data set that are duplicate rows. I currently have around 50k rows of data that identify faults that have been reported by customers and I have put these in time order and would like a single row for the sequence of faults. The following is an example of the output I get, unfortunately there isn't a column for the customer otherwise this would have made it easier.

```
| Fault | Date     | Fault_2 | Date_2   | Fault_3 | Date_3   |
| 123   | 01-02-20 | 456     | 03-02-20 | 789     | 06-02-20 |
| 456   | 03-02-20 | 789     | 06-02-20 |
| 789   | 06-02-20 |
```

What I would like is to write a query that will look at column 'Fault_2' and try and find all the values from that column in the column 'Fault' and if any matches found then this will remove the whole row. This will be the same for the column 'Fault 3'. So the final output I will be left with will be the following:

```
| Fault | Date     | Fault_2 | Date_2   | Fault_3 | Date_3   |
| 123   | 01-02-20 | 456     | 03-02-20 | 789     | 06-02-20 |
```

Would really appreciate if somebody could advise on how I go about achieving this.

My Create Table Script:

```
CREATE TABLE "Faults_Table" 
   (    "FAULT" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "DATE_" DATE, 
    "FAULT_2" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "DATE_2" DATE, 
    "FAULT_3" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "DATE_3" DATE
   )
```

Insert Statements:

```
Insert into Faults_Table (FAULT,DATE_,FAULT_2,DATE_2,FAULT_3,DATE_3) values ('123',to_date('01-FEB-20 10:23:03','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'456',to_date('03-FEB-20 10:23:19','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'789',to_date('06-FEB-20 10:23:29','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into Faults_Table (FAULT,DATE_,FAULT_2,DATE_2,FAULT_3,DATE_3) values ('456',to_date('03-FEB-20 10:23:19','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'789',to_date('06-FEB-20 10:23:29','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),null,null);
Insert into Faults_Table (FAULT,DATE_,FAULT_2,DATE_2,FAULT_3,DATE_3) values ('789',to_date('06-FEB-20 10:23:29','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),null,null,null,null);
```

Thanks

Comment: What happens if the Fault_3 is not found in the column Fault, but it is in Fault_2?

Comment: Thanks CarlosSR, if Fault_3 is not found in column Fault then they won't be a row to delete. If Fault_3 is in Fault_2 then it should already have been deleted as part of looking for Fault_2 in Fault as the sequence of Faults is in order of dates already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `delete` should do the job. It compares faults and dates:

```
delete
  from t a where exists (
    select 1 from t b 
      where (a.fault, a.date_) in ((fault_2, date_2)))
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=924ddcf7f65a37ec94f7659751817a68)</sup>**

Comment: Thanks Ponder, will try that out. I have managed to write something as well.

Answer (score 0):

This selects only the rows where Fault columns are not found in Fault_2 or Fault_3

```
SELECT
t1.*
FROM
table_name t1
WHERE t1.Fault NOT IN (SELECT Fault_2 FROM table_name )
AND t1.Fault NOT IN (SELECT Fault_3 FROM table_name )
```

Comment: Thanks CarlosSR, this gives me an empty set of results. Btw I have added my create and insert statements in my original question. Thanks once again.

Comment: CarlosSR, I think the reason for the empty results is because the where clause is asking to look for the fault '123' in the first row therefore the first row is also being removed.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to write the following query, which works.

```
SELECT
  t1.*
FROM
  faults_table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM faults_table T2
                  WHERE T1.FAULT = T2.FAULT_2)
                  ;
```